# Como hacer que python tome el nombre de usuario y lo ponga en el "camino" (ej: C:/Users/USUARIO/etc)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo este programa que es para copiar unos archivos de una carpeta a otra y quiero que se pueda usar en otras pc´s pero no logro conseguir que python tome el nombre de usuario y lo ponga en el "camino" (ej: C:/Users/etc) ya que me dice que no existe

codigo:

````
import os
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
print (user) # To confirm that it gives the correct username
    
files = ['/mods/[1.12.2]+SecurityCraft+v1.8.21.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', '[1.12.2]+SecurityCraft+v1.8.21.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')

files = ['/mods/EyesInTheDarkness-0.1.0.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'EyesInTheDarkness-0.1.0.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')
    
files = ['/mods/Hwyla-1.8.26-B41_1.12.2.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'Hwyla-1.8.26-B41_1.12.2.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')
    
files = ['/mods/jei_1.12.2-4.16.1.302.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'jei_1.12.2-4.16.1.302.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')

files = ['/mods/journeymap-1.12.2-5.7.1.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'journeymap-1.12.2-5.7.1.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')

files = ['/mods/malisiscore-1.12.2-6.5.1.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'malisiscore-1.12.2-6.5.1.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')

files = ['/mods/malisisdoors-1.12.2-7.3.0.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'malisisdoors-1.12.2-7.3.0.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')

files = ['/mods/PTRLib-1.0.3.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'PTRLib-1.0.3.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods')

files = ['/mods/tombstone-4.1.1-1.12.2.jar']
for f in files:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join('mods', 'tombstone-4.1.1-1.12.2.jar'), 'C:/Users/%s/Desktop/mods') ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Una de las claves de la programación, es la [Abstracción](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstracci%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)). Esto es, crear una forma general de resolver el problema y luego aplicárselo a todas las entradas.

Potenciales problemas que veo, es que los nombres de los archivos tienen una ruta que empieza por `/mod/*.jar`, al estilo **UNIX**. Puedes usar rutas absolutas `C:/.../mods/filename.jar` o relativas `mods/filename.jar` o posicionar el script en la ruta donde están los `.jar` con `os.chdir()`

En tu caso, solo es necesario crear un ciclo que recorra el nombre de todos los elementos a copiar y que los vaya concatenando con la ruta de destino.

```
import os
import getpass
import shutil

user = getpass.getuser()
print (user) # To confirm that it gives the correct username

ruta_src = "C:/ruta_ejemplo/.../mods" # <-- Ejemplo de ruta de los *.jar
os.chdir(ruta_src) # <-- Cambia a este directorio

files = ['[1.12.2]+SecurityCraft+v1.8.21.jar', 'EyesInTheDarkness-0.1.0.jar', 
'Hwyla-1.8.26-B41_1.12.2.jar', 'jei_1.12.2-4.16.1.302.jar', 
'journeymap-1.12.2-5.7.1.jar', 'malisiscore-1.12.2-6.5.1.jar', 
'malisisdoors-1.12.2-7.3.0.jar', 'PTRLib-1.0.3.jar',
'tombstone-4.1.1-1.12.2.jar']

ruta_dst = f'C:/Users/{user}/Desktop/mods'
if not os.path.exists(ruta_dst): # Si no existe el dir de destino
    os.makedirs(ruta_dst) # Crea el directorio

for src in files:
    dst = os.path.join(ruta_dst, src) # Destino tendrá el mismo nombre que el archivo origen
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias!!! ahora funciona perfecto. Disculpa la respuesta tardia, no mire stack durante un tiempo